# Django: how to match apostrophe in URL

Tags: python, regex, django, url

Regex `[\w-.']+` (tested in http://regexr.com/) seems to match correctly for my needs. I need to be able to match English words like "`don't`", "`e.g.`", "`air-condition`" in URLs. I also need to support underscore since I replace spaces in words with it (for example, "air balloon" becomes "`air_balloon`" in URL). So I tried URL configuration `r"^(?P<word>[\w-.']+)/$"` in Django but it gives me an error: `ImproperlyConfigured ... is not a valid regular expression`.

If I alter this a little and use configuration `r"^(?P<word>[\w\-.\']+)/$"` then I don't get the error and words like "`dog`", "`e.g.`" etc. works normally. But in case of "`don't`", I get an error: NoReverseMatch at /application/don't/: Reverse for "view" with arguments '('n#39;t')' not found. Word "`n't`" as an argument is expected in results but it shouldn't give me an error. I supposed I could fix this by using `safe` and/or `safeseq` template filters but no success.

How should I configure my URLs in Django to also correctly match apostrophe in URL? Is there anything else I need to consider to implement this in a secure and optimal Django way? Also, I would like to understand why Django gives me an error for a regex which works exactly as expected in regexr.com.

#### Update:

Pattern which is shown in error message looks like this: `application/(?P<word>[\\w\\-.\\']+)/$`. View is very complex but here is simplified version which hopefully have all relevant parts in it:

```
def search(request, word):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search_form = SearchForm(data=request.POST)

        if search_form.is_valid():
            word = search_form.cleaned_data['word'].replace(' ', '_')

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('search', kwargs={'word': word}))
        else:
            raise SuspiciousOperation
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        results = _search(word)

        return render(request, 'application/result_list.html', results)
```

What happens inside `_search()` shouldn't be related to URLs anymore.

I think I get the error possibly in template rendering since template renders list of related words. It's done in a following way:

```
{% for word in results.words %}
    <a href="{% url 'search' word.split|join:'_' %}">{{ word }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: My suggestion would be to not have URL segments containing apostrophes, quotes, etc at all :)

Comment: I think I have to, unless there are some other solutions. I'm working on a dictionary application so I need to support any expression which could be considered as a valid English word, in a way or another. The most user-friendly solution is to show words correctly in URL, like "don't" instead of "don#39;t" etc.

Comment: Just note that you should not test Python regex patterns at regexr.com that only supports JS regex falvor. Use regex101.com, and set the Python flavor on the left. You will see `[\w-.]` is invalid because `-` cannot form a range between a word char class and a dot (in JS, this hyphen is resolved as a literal hyphen).

Comment: If this is for a search API, you probably want to use querystring arguments rather than URL parameters - eg `/search/?q=don't`. In which case spaces can be encoded using `+`: `/search/?q=air+balloon`.

Comment: This is a search for the API indeed but I prefer not to use more complex looking querystring arguments. For example Oxford Dictionaries and Wiktionary also uses only normal words in URLs, for example https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/don't or https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/don't. I want to do something similar, I think it's more user friendly.

Comment: @m5seppal Could you please show the corresponding view that receives those requests? The regex `r"(?P<word>[.\w\-']+)"` is definitely fine, I guess the error comes from your view (it worked for me at least).

Comment: You could try `r'^(?P<word>[^/]+)/$'` i.e. match anything up to a forward slash. Works with `reverse` too.

Comment: @whp: your suggestion works and now I see how the page is rendered. Link "n't" looks correct but when I link it, it redirects to URL /application/n&%2339;t/ and page title is in form "n&#39;t". So I think the problem is not in the URLs at all and current URL pattern should work if I just fix how Django replaces apostrophe with "&#39;". Any ideas how to fix that are welcome.